# Почему правильно писать "предлАгать"?

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте!
Почему правильно писать "предлАгать"? (предлОг, предлОжить)

Answer (score 2):

В корне *лаг-* перед суффиксом *-а-* пишется *а*, в корне *лож-* не перед суффиксом *-а-* пишется *о*. В корне *лог-, лож-* , если он находится под ударением, всегда пишется *о*. Например: *предлагать, предложить, залог*. Исключение: *полог.*

Comment: "В корне лог-, лож- под ударением всегда о". Как это надо понимать? Так, что правильно, например, *предлОжить*?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, имелось в виду, что если корень под ударением, то там должна стоять "о" (а не наоборот: если в корне стоит "о", то корень под ударением).

Comment: Да, мне тоже формулировочка "запала".

Comment: Бред какой-то. Всю жизнь я писал предлОжить. и проверял его массой проверочных слов: предложение, предлог и т.д. А теперь вот тебе на, причём многие при этом вообще забывают писать букву Ё